# A single word for overreaching / overestimating ones own abilities?

Tags: synonyms, slang

Is there a single word slang or otherwise that can describe

> A person who continually overreaches or overestimates their own abilities.

and example usage

> "Bob's such a `word`: He always injures himself."

The closest non-slang term I could find was narcissism, however, this isn't really appropriate. Rather, an expected characteristic for someone with this trait.

In sporting slang, there are several terms:

- Kook (generic extreme sports, slightly abused in this context)
- Jerry (in snowsports e.g. "JerryOfTheDay")
- Tryhard (strictly two words in my opinion)

Comment: M-W lists the agent noun _overreacher_.

Comment: bonehead? joker? bluffer? big talker?

Comment: Per your example, the expression "he bites off more than he can chew" is a possibility.

Comment: Because there isn't, I can't explain why not.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is there a single word slang or otherwise that can describe A person who continually overreaches or overestimates their own abilities.

For myself it would depend largely on how and why I was planning to use it.

I've pondered that same question before regarding which word to use, and it seems that after considering presumptuous, impudent and all the other entries in the thesaurus, I always end up using overconfident.

Answer (score 1):

Conceit

Noun: excessive pride in oneself.

Ex:"he was puffed up with conceit"

Similar:
vanity
narcissism
conceitedness
self-love
self-admiration
self-adulation
self-regard
egotism
egoism
egocentricity
egomania
pride
arrogance
hubris
boastfulness
cockiness
self-importance
immodesty
self-satisfaction
smugness
complacency
amour propre
big-headedness

https://www.google.com/search?q=coneit&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari

Comment: This doesn't really fit the sample sentence from the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Prima donna** may come close, [Oxford English Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prima_donna) defines it as:

> A very temperamental person with an inflated view of their own talent or importance.

This may not be exactly what you look for, since it includes the part *very temperamental*, but the latter part of the definition surely fits.

The rest of this answer mistakenly comes with adjectives rather than a noun, I'll leave it just in case it is of interest.
[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self-conceited) defines **self-conceited** as:

> having an excessive sense of one's own importance, abilities and value

Another word to describe it would be **overconfident**, [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overconfident) defines it as

> excessively confident *(British English)*, or
>
> confident without adequate reason; too confident *(American English)*

To put the previous definition in context, one of the definitions for *confident*, according to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/confident):

> If a person or their manner is *confident*, they feel sure about their own abilities, qualities, or ideas.

Comment: The OP test sentence requires a noun.

Comment: @NigelJ thanks for pointing that out, I added a noun which may be suitable.

Answer (score -1):

***Hubris***

> exaggerated pride or self-confidence

Source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hubris)

Comment: Bob’s such a *hubris*...

Comment: is that not grammatically correct?

Comment: You can have hubris, you can be accused of hubris, you can display hubris, but you cannot ***be*** a hubris.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but hubris can also be defined as [dangerous overconfidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubris)

Comment: You are not wrong, but you can’t ***be***” a dangerous overconfidence” either.

Comment: not sure, but in the Philippines, there are instances that we use such word like that

Comment: @ArchieAzares it's like _confidence_ or _patience_, you can have it, but you cannot be it.